# Deploy Angular Universal on IIS

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, angular-universal

I Have a Angular Universal Project and I need to run that on the IIS and must be run `main.js` in first time .

[image]

I Try for some Wat but it Not worked :

A : Install IISnode

B : Active `CGI` into the  `Turn windows features on or off`

C : Using this `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="/main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="nodejs">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/main.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite> 

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="node_modules" />
      <add segment="iisnode" />
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

but its not worked for me , and Show me this Error :

[image]

**How Can i Solve this Problem  and run Angular universal in on IIS ?**

Comment: Follow the steps to redeploy the application and try: https://www.mousa-alsheikh.com/post/17